# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class Button

Tags: java, android

I got this crash for Android API 16 it works fine on API 19 and above.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.tff")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

here are all my logs

```
09-20 16:16:09.197 10921-10921/com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp/com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class Button
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/btn_signin.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080064
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2228)
    at com.huawei.android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:632)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:641)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3562)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:640)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:70)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:280)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag ripple
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2222)
    at com.huawei.android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:632) 
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:641) 
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3562) 
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:640) 
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:70) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073) 
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:280) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my xml file for my main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C I T Y K R U I Z"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="USER"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="(c) 2018 by SWAQ Dev"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/transparent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txt_forgot_password"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_signin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTINUE"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/btnContinue"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding the logcat too. Also, it looks like error comes from a `Button` which you don't have-neither added a `Button` in your codes

Comment: It looks like your error says the exception is in a XML file - you might want to include the relevant XML as well.

Comment: Here is my logo

Comment: `09-20 16:16:09.197 10921-10921/com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp/com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class Button
`

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class Button`

Comment: Please don't use comments to add logs. Instead, try editing your question and add them as codes. Also, there will be xml codes needed to check codes from xml side since it comes from a `Button` which you might initialized it wrong or might be another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Calligraphy library **before inflating layout**, there must be other issues in future too. So, as [the documentation](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy) already wrote, define calligraphy inside `onCreate()` method and after inflating layout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.tff")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
}
```

This should solve most of the issues but, there are other issues too:

---

> **Resources$NotFoundException:** File `res/drawable/btn_signin.xml` from
>   drawable resource ID

It couldn't find such file from `drawable/btn_signin.xml` also.

> Binary XML file line #2: **invalid drawable tag ripple**

There is another issue with *drawable tag ripple* which you should check the codes from `drawable` related file.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to read stacktrace carefuly, as despite of the high noise it contains some hints here and there. Namely `Caused by` entry may cast some light:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
    File res/drawable/btn_signin.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080064
```

this basically means that your `btn_signin.xml` file is referencing resource that is not present in API 16. I strongly recommend you run `Lint` on your project.

Comment: `that is not present in API 16` Not really agree with this since I have just checked the [library codes](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy/blob/master/calligraphy/build.gradle) which represents `minSdkVersion` **14 and up** so that shouldn't be the case in here. However, as you might saw, there is: `android:background="@drawable/btn_signin"` inside the `Button` in the xml side  which does not seem to be exist so.